# Dumping values of multi-dimensional arrays into gtkwave for Verilator

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am able to do a VCD dump of multidimensional arrays using the `$dumpfile()` and `$dumpvars()` commands in the `iverilog` simulator, but the same commands are not working for Verilator.
Kindly do let me know if there is any way to do the dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verilator has limits on the size of arrays it will dump. See these two switches:

```
 --trace-max-array <depth>   Maximum bit width for tracing
 --trace-max-width <width>   Maximum array depth for tracing
```

Comment: ..thanks a lot for the info but can you tell me where can I find these two switches or where should I insert them myself to make it take my values.

Comment: https://www.veripool.org/projects/verilator/wiki/Manual-verilator#VERILATION-ARGUMENTS